# Access attributes when values are objects in reduce function (CouchDB)

Tags: javascript, couchdb

I'm trying to write a query in CouchDB that will get names and ages of all people who have the maximum age, grouping by gender and isActive status. There is only one data document being searched. As an intermediate step to understanding how to write the reduce function when the values are objects, I've written a query that just returns the maximum age within each group, but this has been unsuccessful. The following map and reduce functions return the appropriate keys, which are the 4 combinations of male/female and true/false, but the values always come back 0 in all four groups.

Why does this view not return the maximum age for each group?

Map Function:

```
function(doc){
    for (var i in doc.data){
        var person = doc.data[i];
        emit([person.gender, person.isActive], {'age':person.age, 'name': person.name});
    }
}
```

Reduce Function:

```
function(keys, values, rereduce){
    var maxAge = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
        if(values[i].age > maxAge){
            maxAge = values[i].age;
        }
    }
    return maxAge;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not covering the `rereduce` case. Your reducer needs to deal with both the values emitted from the map function, but also values returned by itself:

```
function(keys, values, rereduce){
    if (rereduce) {
      return values.reduce(function(a, b) {
        return Math.max(a, b);
      });
    }
    var maxAge = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
        if(values[i].age > maxAge){
            maxAge = values[i].age;
        }
    }
    return maxAge
}
```

In general, using custom reduce functions can lead to performance-related problems down the line. If at all possible, prefer the built-in reducers that are a lot more efficient.

Also, you may be well served by splitting out the `data` array into separate documents instead, to lessen the chance of getting update conflicts.